# Change first line color of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to change a `UILabels` first line's color. It's not working for some reason. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = 
 [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
   initWithAttributedString: label.attributedText];

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
             value:[UIColor redColor] 
             range:[label.text rangeOfString:@"\n"];];
[label setAttributedText: text];
```

I don't see any changes in the first line.

Comment: your usage of `rangeOfString` is not correct...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here

```
[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
         value:[UIColor redColor] 
         range:[label.text rangeOfString:@"\n"]];
```

It will color only `\n`

You need range from `0` to start of `\n`

---

Edit : You can try this code (it's not tested but should work)

```
NSRange rangeOfNewLine = [label.text rangeOfString:@"\n"];
NSRange newRange = NSMakeRange(0, rangeOfNewLine.location);

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
           value:[UIColor redColor]
           range:newRange];
```